# to check whether an android phone have flash or not through programming

Tags: android, flash

When somebody download my app I want to notify him that whether his phone is having flash or not. Please help me to get code for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Context context = this;
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

// if device support flash?
if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
    //yes
    Log.i("camera", "This device has flash supported!");
}else{
    //no
    Log.i("camera", "This device has no flash support!");
}
```

Comment: sorry, I can't upvote right now as I am new to stack overflow